# How to get camera exact white balance parameters value when it is in auto mode?

Tags: android, parameters, android-camera

I've got a [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) object with white balance setted to auto. Is it possible to find real white balance parameter which is applied at the moment when I'm taking a picture?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this.

You may be able to find what you're looking for by inspecting the Exif metadata for the final JPEG (after the picture has been taken) to find the ColorSpace tag.

Based on the color space specification, you can find out the illuminant white point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space#Specifications

Comment: I was trying to do it but JPEG Exif metadata returns WHITEBALANCE_AUTO result.

Comment: Check the ColorSpace Exif tag. I've updated my answer to include that.