# How to Measure camera exact white balance parameters value in auto white balance mode?

Tags: colors, camera

I have some images and I want to extract the exact color of them. Is it possible to find out which kelvin temperature were used by camera in auto white balance mode? I read this link below for that is for two years ago but by that answer in Wikipedia I couldn't calculate AWB parameter.
This is a part of my thesis and I really need to find a way to estimate the kelvin temperature that camera applied on the images. my images are almost one color and I want to know the real color of that.
Thanks.

Link:
[How to get camera exact white balance parameters value when it is in auto mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716354/how-to-get-camera-exact-white-balance-parameters-value-when-it-is-in-auto-mode)

Comment: Do you have the some camera you are using each time?

Comment: Also - how is this related to programming?

Comment: Yes, I use same camera for all of the images.

Comment: Because I am trying to develop an app in android and for image processing procedure I need this information!

Comment: What is the camera you use?

Comment: It's an smartphone it cannot take a photo in RAW mode.

Comment: Any specific smartphone?  Like `iPhone 4s`, or `Samsung Galaxy 5s`

Comment: Do you have any idea about it. I'm trying to detect nitrogen status of plants by smartphone and I think if know it the accuracy will increase.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the top, industry standard tool is ExifTool by Phil Harvey.

Phil is very good about keeping up with the new cameras and is admirably conscientious about tracking down reported problems.

```
D:\pic\pedernales.river\nef\p5\>exiftool.exe -ColorTemperature -Tint *t.tif
Color Temperature               : 3750
Tint                            : -10
```

And if you are dealing with RAW data, there are 2 pre-Bayer interpolation tags of interest (actually the ~same numbers A=B*256)

```
WB_GRBGLevels         =>  256 413 353 256
WB_RBLevels           =>  1.61328125 1.37890625 1 1
```

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

There is also a very slick GUI that wraps by BogdanH it if you need it.
http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=2750.0

And an indispensable Perl Module: cpan install Image::ExifTool
There is also a telepathic interface, but I can't remember where I put it. ;)

```
BrianP
```

exif exiftool Image::ExifTool